# Why do we use CYK algorithm?

Tags: formal-languages

Why do we use the CYK algorithm? In my book is written that with CYK algorithm you can faster see if a word is generated by a given Grammer. However I dont get it, because I need like 5 min in order to divide the word into other subwords.. and so on and only few seconds just to derive the word using the predicates.

Comment: We don’t use CYK. There are linear time algorithms for grammars used in practice.

Comment: CYK is intended for use by computer and on long texts. This is not quite what you’ve had experience with.

Comment: CYK works for *all* grammars, most other parsing algorithms work only for non-ambiguous ones.

Comment: What is "my book"? Explicit quotations and citations improve questions.

Answer (score 0):

We use CYK algorithm to check whether the give string is present in the given context free language or not.

By using the CYK algorithm we can check the string belongs to given CFL or not.And also we can find the substrings of that string present in that language.

The process used in the CYK algorithm is

1.Construct a table DP for size n × n.

2.If w = e (empty string) and S -> e is a rule in G then we accept the string else we reject.

3.For i = 1 to n:

For each variable A:

```
 We check if A -> b is a rule and b = wi
```

for some i:

```
    If so, we place A in cell (i, i) of our table.
```

4.For l = 2 to n:

For i = 1 to n-l+1:

```
   j = i+l-1

    For k = i to j-1:

       For each rule A -> BC: 

    We check if (i, k) cell contains B and (k + 1, j) cell contains C:

         If so, we put A in cell (i, j) of our table.
```

5.We check if S is in (1, n):

If so, we accept the string

Else, we reject.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm):

> The importance of the CYK algorithm stems from its high efficiency in certain situations.

In particular, its relevance is that it allows parsing an arbitrary context-free grammar, with running time that is polynomial in the input size (in particular, cubic in the input size).  Many other parsing strategies cannot handle arbitrary context-free grammars.

There are other parsing strategies that are typically faster in practice, including ones that can handle arbitrary grammars, but CYK is particularly simple and has this nice property of being able to handle an arbitrary grammar, so it is handy to present in an introductory class.